# UITextField textFieldDidEndEditing not called from enable to disabled UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

In Swift, I have a UITextField, textA, and a UITextField, textB.

textA sometimes will be disabled, but textB is always enabled.

textA is disabled using:

```
textA.enabled = false
```

When I click outside of textB, the keyboard is supposed to resign

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

This delegate function fires, with one exception. If I am editing textB, and click to textA when it is disabled, textFieldDidEndEditing does not call for textB, and the keyboard remains open.

It is worth nothing that if textA is enabled, and I click it after editing textB, the textFieldDidEndEditing does fire for textB.

Any ideas on how to get the delegate to fire?

Answer (score 1):

When textA is not enabled, it will not register a tap and therefore cannot become the firstResponder so textB remains as the responder.

Comment: correct, `textA.enabled = false` means that touch events are ignored, so you're not actually ending the editing on textB.

Comment: Is there a way to disable editing on textA, so that textB will end editing on textA tap?

Comment: You can leave textA enabled and implement `- textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` delegate to not allow editing of textA

Comment: I set - textFieldShouldBeginEditing to return false, and the result is the same. 'textFieldDidEndEditing' does not fire for textB

Comment: You can use the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` to `resignFirstResponder` of textB before you return False